# Downloading the Google search results page using Linux commands

Tags: ubuntu, wget

When I try using wget command, the page which gets downloaded contains only the lefthand side part. I want the right-hand side part of the search-results page, which is called Knowledge Graph. Can anybody help me out in this please?

Comment: Maybe check using your browser's "View Source" functionality first -- wget will not evaluate Javascript for you to pull in AJAXy content.

Comment: Google has a search API. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use any utility other than wget then try some of the command line browsers referenced in this Askubuntu question:

- [Browsing the internet from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line)

#### Tools

- Elinks
- w3m
- lynx
- links2